# Where are the pmset settings saved?

Tags: terminal, big-sur, pmset

In which path exactly are the `pmset` settings saved?  The manpage says it's stored here.  However, I couldn't find any settings there.

> The macOS Energy Saver preference file is stored
> at:
> `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.PowerManagement.plist`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/Library/Preferences/com.apple.PowerManagement.plist`

I recommend [EasyFind](https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware) to track down system files, as Spotlight won't search them. It doesn't index, so it's slower, but if it's there, it will find it.